# Htaccess and restfull app

Tags: .htaccess, restful-url

I'm not very good at htaccess, so looking for some help here. I have a web app running at

```
myserver.com/index.html
```

And I'm sending the requests (`GET,PUT,DELETE`) to a controller:

```
myserver.com/controller.php?id=5
```

Is there a way that I can use htaccess to submit through a url like

```
myserver.com/controller/5
```

I've toyed with my `htaccess` but just manage to create 500 errors when trying to hit the `index.html` page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send a request like: `myserver.com/controller/5` and you want to use mod_rewrite to rewrite it back to `/controller.php?id=5`, you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Or less general:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?controller/([^/]+)$ /controller.php?id=$1 [L]
```